# Prevent Wordpress From Rewriting Capital Letters to Lowercase Letters

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I am hoping that someone can help me locate where this rewrite is coming from (searched all my nginx files and its not there. I'm guessing it's a WP rewrite in includes?) and help me prevent the rewrite from converting my uppercase path letters to lowercase letters.

Example: If you navigate to this image (below) in a browser please notice that the URL is rewritten. This is not a rewrite I created but it works out because users that are hitting my old blog images which are indexed online will need the rewrite to view them. BUT the uppercase letter 'H' is converted to lowercase 'h' so the user will not be able to view it! If you modify the lowercase to an uppercase in the URL string and hit the page you can now see the image.

Can someone please help me solve this issue? I cannot rename all my images by the way. Also I am using nginx and i hear that you are not aloud to remove case sensitivity from nginx like you can with apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx includes a method for converting uppercase to lowercase:

```
rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri_low;
```

make sure you config doesn't have this kind of conversion.