# Wordpress Editor url link with uppercase

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I tried to add HTML code via editor to my WordPress page.

The problem is when I add code with uppercase words like:

https://example.com/WP-content/

After saving the page, it changes the link to lowercase words https://example.com/wp-content/

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Searching your title gives me this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-changes-urls-to-all-lowercase-automatically/

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702040/prevent-wordpress-from-rewriting-capital-letters-to-lowercase-letters

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, which HTML are you trying to add to the page?